# Are there more search paths than in sys.path?

Tags: python, sys.path, module-search-path

I thought that the sys.path was a complete list of *all* search paths for Python modules.

However, on my Ubuntu machine, '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/' is where almost all my modules are and that path is not in sys.path. And I can still import any module on that path.

EDIT, NOT TRUE: Even if I set the sys.path to the empty list, I can still import from that path.

Where does this implicit knowledge of the dist-packages path come from? And are there any other paths in this implicit group of search paths, or whatever it is?

EDIT: It seems like the second part of my post is not true. Indeed, "sys.path = []", will mean that I can not import anything, not even from my current working directory. My apologies.

Comment: instead of making all these confusing edits and adding "EDIT" and "NOT TRUE", just rip out the parts that aren't true so that your question is clear and understandable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note the mention of an *installation-dependent default* in the [following](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path):

> **6.1.2. The Module Search Path**
>
> When a module named `spam` is imported, the interpreter searches for a
>   file named `spam.py` in the directory containing the input script and
>   then in the list of directories specified by the environment variable
>   `PYTHONPATH`. This has the same syntax as the shell variable `PATH`, that
>   is, a list of directory names. When `PYTHONPATH` is not set, or when the
>   file is not found there, the search continues in an
>   **installation-dependent default path**; on Unix, this is usually
>   `.:/usr/local/lib/python`.
>
> Actually, modules are searched in the list of directories given by the
>   variable `sys.path` which is initialized from the directory containing
>   the input script (or the current directory), `PYTHONPATH` and **the
>   installation-dependent default**. This allows Python programs that know
>   what they’re doing to modify or replace the module search path. Note
>   that because the directory containing the script being run is on the
>   search path, it is important that the script not have the same name as
>   a standard module, or Python will attempt to load the script as a
>   module when that module is imported. This will generally be an error.
>   See section Standard Modules for more information.

**edit** On my Ubuntu box, `/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages` is present in `sys.path`. If I clear `sys.path` and then try to import a module from the above directory, that no longer works. This suggests that the interpreter has no implicit knowledge of that directory and finds it via `sys.path`.

**edit** When you conduct your experiments, make sure that you modify `sys.path` right at the start of your Python session. If you `import X`, then clear `sys.path`, and then `import X` again, the latter will not fail even though `X` is no longer on `sys.path`.

Answer (score 1):

[Module Search Path](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path)

> Actually, modules are searched in the list of directories given by the
>   variable sys.path which is initialized from the directory containing
>   the input script (or the current directory), PYTHONPATH and the
>   installation- dependent default.

You are running into the  installation- dependent default.

[More Information on installation-dependent search paths](http://docs.python.org/library/site.html)

Comment: No, I read it differently from you. It says, that sys.path is the search path, and that sys.path is initialized from the installation-dependent default. But this supposedly installation dependent default does not show in sys.path.